# Указатели в языке C

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Указываю значение из файла указателю newstr через функцию strtok(), это значение присваивается указателю numofstd, который при определенных условиях if присваивается указателю numofstrmax. При последующем проходе цикла значение numofstd меняется и, несмотря на не выполнение условий if, меняется и значение указателя numofstrmax. Как это можно исправить?

Содержимое файла:
Alexey Ivanov Sergeevich;23;44;52;65
Alexand Ivanov Ivanovich;23;44;64;21

```
FILE *fp;

char str[100];
char *newstr;
int maxnum = 0;
int maxsum = 0;
int num = 0;
int max = 0;
int min = 999999;
float sr = 0;
char *numofstrmax;
char *numofstrmin;
char *numofmaxsum;
char *numofstd;

void Arifmetic() {
if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(str, 100, fp);

    newstr = strtok(str, ";");
    numofstd = newstr;
    while (newstr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", newstr);

        newstr = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (newstr != NULL) {
            num = atoi(newstr);
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
                numofstrmax = numofstd;
            }
            if (num < min) {
                min = num;
                numofstrmin = numofstd;
            }
            sr += num;
            maxnum += num;
        }
    }
    if (maxnum > maxsum) {
        maxsum = maxnum;
        numofmaxsum = numofstd;
    }
    maxnum = 0;
    n++;
}

fclose(fp);

printf("\n%s%d%s%s\n","Максимальный балл: ", max, " у ", numofstrmax);
printf("%s%d%s%s\n","Минимальный балл: ", min, " у ", numofstrmin);
printf("%s%d%s%s\n","Максимальный балл за все модули: ", maxsum, " у ", numofmaxsum);
printf("%s%f\n", "Средний балл: ", sr / (n * 4));

main();
}
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что у вас меняются значения указателей? Значения указателей у вас не меняются. Меняются у вас данные, на которые эти указатели указывают. На каждой итерации цикла вы читаете новые данные из файла в один и тот же буфер `str`. А ваши указатели указывают именно в этот буфер. То есть вы сами втихаря "подменяете" данные под указателями.

Answer (score 0):

`numofmaxsum` является указателем. Когда условие `if (maxnum > maxsum)` выполняется, то `numofmaxsum` присваивается значение `numofstd`.

С этого момента вне зависимости от условия `if (maxnum > maxsum)` `numofmaxsum` будет постоянно указывать на `numofstd`.

Как один из вариантов решения, Вы можете объявить `numofmaxsum` как массив с известным размером:

```
char numofmaxsum[256];
```

Перезаписывайте его значение, когда условие `if (maxnum > maxsum)` выполняется:

```
memset(numofmaxsum, 0, 256);
strncpy(numofmaxsum, numofstd, 255);
```

Обратите внимание, что мы используем функцию `strncpy` - она копирует либо всю строку, либо максимум байт, указанных в третьем аргументе. Это обеспечивает защиту от переполнения буфера. Мы передаём значение длины буфера минус 1, чтобы оставить место для завершающего `NULL`.

В зависимости от максимальной длины ожидаемой строки, используйте буфер подходящего размера.

Comment: Каких только извращений ни придумывается для того, чтобы применить `strncpy` в этой роли... Вот `memset`.

Comment: @AnT, просветите, что не так с `strncpy`. Я не являюсь профессиональным программистом, поэтому буду рад узнать что-то новое от Вас.